fullCalendar is throwing undefined error on successCallback after correctly parsing the response from the backend
I am using fullCalendar 5.5.1 to display some events on screen. I fetch the data from the database and it is working as expected. The only issue I have is that in some situations I receive an error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: successCallback(...) is undefined

It happens if the response from the database is empty but it also happens after fullCalendar parses all the data returned from the database (like it is not stopping after managing all the records).
To avoid the first to happen I put a check on the response length so that if it is 0 it stops parsing and it works fine but I don't know how to avoid the other situation.
A sample of my data is (printed from console)
0: Object { title: "Evento di test 1 - 7 hours", start: "2024-06-01T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 7 }​
1: Object { title: "Evento di test 2 - 3 hours", start: "2024-06-01T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 3 }
2: Object { title: "Evento di test 3 - 3 hours", start: "2024-06-06T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 3 }
3: Object { title: "Evento di test 4 - 7 hours", start: "2024-06-09T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 7 }
4: Object { title: "Evento di test 5 - 4 hours", start: "2024-06-20T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 4 }
5: Object { title: "Evento di test 6 - 6 hours", start: "2024-06-22T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 6 }
6: Object { title: "Evento di test 7 - 3 hours", start: "2024-06-28T22:00:00.000Z", duration: 3 }

While the code I am using is:
        var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: 'local',
            customButtons: {
                newEvent: {
                    text: 'New record',
                    click: function () {
                        alert('clicked the custom button!');
                    }
                }
            },
            headerToolbar: {
                right: 'prev,next today',
                left: 'title',
                center: 'newEvent',
                //right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
            },
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            defaultAllDay: true,
            events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                let user = sessione.profilo.id;
                let project = sessione.progettoAttivo.id;
                //let start = info.start.valueOf();
                //let end = info.end.valueOf();
                let start = info.startStr;
                let end = info.endStr;
                smartAxios.get("/timesheet?user=" + user + "&project=" + project + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    let prevDate = '';
                    let totDuration = 0;
                    if(response.data.length==0){
                        console.log('no data for this month');
                    }else{
                        successCallback(
                            response.data.map(function (eventEl) {
                                console.log(eventEl);
                                return {
                                    title: eventEl.title,
                                    start: eventEl.start,
                                    color: '#007bff',
                                    textColor: 'white',
                                    allDay: true
                                }
                            }),
                            response.data.forEach(function (element) {
                                let date = new Date(element.start);
                            
                                let year = date.getFullYear();
                                let month = ((date.getMonth()+1).toString().length < 2) ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1) : (date.getMonth()+1);
                                //let month = date.getMonth()+1;
                                let day = ((date.getDate()).toString().length < 2) ? "0"+(date.getDate()) : (date.getDate());
                                //let day = date.getDate();
                                date= year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
                                if (date == prevDate) {
                                    totDuration = totDuration + element.duration;
                                } else {
                                    prevDate = date;
                                    totDuration = element.duration;
                                }
                                if (totDuration > 8) {
                                    $('#calendar').find('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
                                }
                                console.log(prevDate, totDuration);
                            })
                        )
                        .catch(function(err){
                            console.log(err)
                            $(document).Toasts('create', { autohide: true, delay: 750, title: 'Timesheet',class: 'bg-danger', body:'Error trying to retrieve data'})
                            
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
        });


You say in some situations I receive an error...but then the two cases you mention are 1) when no results are returned, and 2) when results are returned. This sounds like all situations (aside from the axios request failing entirely of course). Are there some other scenarios where it doesn't happen? It's hard to imagine what they would be. So are you really saying you always get this error? The way you describe the problem is a little bit confusing.

if I'm not mistake your .catch(function(err){ is in the wrong place as well. It looks like it's attached to the successCallback function call, but that doesn't return a Promise. Surely it's supposed to be attached to the smartAxios.get call?

First let's see the error:

TypeError: successCallback(...) is undefined

the error means that you are trying to call (call as function) a variable that is actually undefined
now let's see the source of the variable: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback)
it is from a parameter, we don't have control over how it is passed, so maybe it is not passed as undefined in some cases
now to the solution:
you can do this to call it only when it exists: successCallback?.()


I can do it but the result is just the same:  "TypeError: successCallback(...) is undefined warning" is printed by the failureCallback... and this happens after all the correct data have been parsed. So after it successfully goes through all the response

the error means that you are trying to call (call as function) a variable that is actually undefined I know that, but this shouldn't happen.. it should stop after parsing all the results

@LelioFaieta
di you try successCallback?.() ?
i think that would stop the error, but still you should dig more into why it is undefined in the first place

I can help more if you create a stackblitz or codesandbox

that could mean that in case of error there won't be a successCallback...no, this makes no sense. FullCalendar can't know, when it triggers the event source function that it passes these things to, whether the AJAX call within that function is going to fail or not - because 1) fullcalendar doesn't control that code, or know anything about what's inside the event source function (there might be not even be an ajax call in there!), and 2) the ajax call hasn't happened yet. It cannot possibly know whether to omit the successCallback parameter or not. So it doesn't do that.

you are totally right, i didn't read it carefully, I apologize for the mistake, i wll editt my answer
